# How do I best deal with this information overload?

Tags: website-design, web-app, tables, info-visualisation

[image: example]

This represents a category of job times, which are broken down into timeframes.
Timeframes have:

`Total` (if fake is 0, shown without T, else with)
`Fake` (hidden if zero) as F
`Built` as B
`Scheduled` as S
`Jobs` as Jobs
`Buffer` as Buffer
`Techs` as Techs
`Contractors` as Contractors

The business owners want it all there per timeframe explicitly as I've tried to hide some of it in tooltips before and the suggestion was declined.

Comment: Can you elaborate/clarify a bit, the logic you describe is confusing?

Comment: Sure. The bar at the top that goes from 8 to 19:00 is the min and max times of the category. The earliest timeframe starts at 8am and the latest timeframe ends at 5pm. Each timeframe within a category has the following information that needs to be explicitly displayed: Total, Fake, Built, Scheduled, Buffer, Job Count, Tech Count and Contractor Count. All of those are just counts essentially. Its a ton of information, especially given that this screen generally has multiple categories all displayed at once, each with multiple timeframes.

Comment: What value are you getting by placing it into a horizontal time view?

Comment: Being able to, at a glance, compare timeframes that are that exact or similar times across multiple categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some suggestions to cope with information overload are:

- **Be flexible**: provide both short and extended versions of information:
  [image]
- **Make accent on non-zero values** for quick visual detection
- **Support visual analysis** with background, i.e. zebra-colors, etc. See picture: 
  [image]
- **Provide search by example**: let the system automatically find exact and similar timeframes based on your selection, see picture above
- **Provide detailed comparision** for selected processes based on quantitative data:
  [image]

Also keep in mind, the visual comparision is good for quick and dirty qualitative analysis. So the last point on quantitative comparision could be very useful.

Comment: Thank you, this is great advice. What program did you use to create these examples?

Comment: @CGross I use [Xara Designer](http://www.xara.com/us/).